# CocoaPods Error pod install HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

First foray into CocoaPods (and I'm not very happy with it!). I followed all of the instructions. When I do `pod install` this is what i get:

> Analyzing dependencies
>   Downloading dependencies 
> Using AFNetworking (2.4.1) 
> Using Braintree
>   (3.4.0) 
> Generating Pods project Integrating client project
>
> [!] The `MyProject [Debug]` target overrides the
>   `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead
>   to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The `MyProject [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS`
>   build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead
>   to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The `MyProject [Release]` target overrides the
>   `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject.release.xcconfig'. This can lead
>   to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.
>
> [!] The `MyProject [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS`
>   build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject.release.xcconfig'. This can lead
>   to problems with the CocoaPods installation
>       - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
>       - Remove the build settings from the target.

Here is my Podfile:

> source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
>
> target 'ActivFocus' do
>           pod 'Braintree' # Alternatively: pod 'Braintree', '~> 3.0.0'
>           pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0" 
> end
>   
>   target 'ActivFocusTests' do
>           pod 'Braintree' # Alternatively: pod 'Braintree', '~> 3.0.0'
>           pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0" 
> end

I don't know how to follow the suggestion:

> ```
> - Use the '$(inherited)' flag, or
> - Remove the build settings from the target.
> ```

EDIT: This is the Xcode error that I get when trying to build the project as a result of this:

> Ld
>   /Users/randy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-epuhpnvywesozcamslrdbksivzae/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/MyProject
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/randy/Development/MyProject/iOSApp/MyProject
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/randy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-epuhpnvywesozcamslrdbksivzae/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -L/Users/randy/Development/MyProject/iOSApp/MyProject/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK
>   -L/Users/randy/Development/MyProject/iOSApp/MyProject -L/Users/randy/Development/MyProject/iOSApp/MyProject/MyProject/libs/ios_libs/simplify/vendor/ocmock
>   -F/Users/randy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-epuhpnvywesozcamslrdbksivzae/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/randy/Development/MyProject/iOSApp/MyProject/MyProject/libs/ios_libs/simplify
>   -F/Users/randy/Development/MyProject/iOSApp/MyProject/MyProject -F/Users/randy/Development/MyProject/iOSApp/MyProject -filelist /Users/randy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-epuhpnvywesozcamslrdbksivzae/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyProject.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreData -framework QuartzCore -framework MediaPlayer -framework
>   CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods-MyProject
>   -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/randy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-epuhpnvywesozcamslrdbksivzae/Build/Intermediates/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyProject_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/randy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-epuhpnvywesozcamslrdbksivzae/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/MyProject
>
> ld: library not found for -lPods-ActivFocus clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: do you resolve this @usr55410.

Comment: did you try 'pod setup' before 'pod install' ?

Comment: try these steps http://stackoverflow.com/a/37341045/3472073

Answer (score 8):

If there is no manual overriding done for header search path, try deleting the pod config files which is added to your project. This can be found at `YourProject\Pods` (and not in pods project, check the image). Try running pod install once again and check.

[image: Pod Config File]

If you have manually added header path, then ignore the warning and add an inherited flag in the search path as below

[image: Inherited Flag to the header search path]

Comment: Hi how do I get that window? I have the problem but deleting pod configs and install again doesnt work so I want to try adding the PODS_ROOT thing manually.

Comment: Removing those xcconfigs and running pod install is the trick.