# Manifest.lock gives warning about Podfile.lock, what caused?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, manifest

1 - I have tried update cocoapods and re-install pod for my project many times. But **Manifest.lock** still looks like having a problem. My app works well. Can It be affect something later? How Can I solve it?

2 - In addition **Pods_Projectname.framework** has red title in Xcode navigator. I continue developing my app but these things worried me, I don't know what happened. I couldn't find solution.

[image: Manifest file error]

> Still continue problem, In addition looks below problems:

**Build Phases - Embed Pods Frameworks:**

```
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName-frameworks.sh"
```

**Build Phases - Copy Pods Resources:**

```
"${SRCROOT}/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName-resources.sh"
```

Comment: Have you tried to turn it off and on again ?? To uninstall CocoaPod : follow this link http://superuser.com/a/686319  To reinstall it follow the other answer. PS: it actually solve this bug for me, but I can't be sure it will work for you

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65783259/5175709

Answer (score 4):

Try these steps

1. Quit Xcode
2. Clear /*YourUserHomeFolder*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
3. Remove **Pods** folder and **Podfile.lock** file
4. (in terminal)**$ gem install cocoapods**
5. (in terminal in your project)**$ pod install**

Comment: Still same problem, updated question after trying these steps.

Comment: @tobeiosdev what Xcode version and Pods version do you use?

Comment: cocoapods-1.0.0 / Xcode Version 7.3.1, gem install cocoapods doesn't work with me. Instead, I have used `sudo gem install cocoapods -V`

Comment: Just tried all of them like this but not solved, http://stackoverflow.com/a/27119922/6135652

Comment: @tobeiosdev i've updated the answer by added 3th step

Comment: I have tried many things before pod install process, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to project folder.
2. Find Pods folder and delete everything that you have there including `Manifest.lock`.
3. Go back to project folder and delete `Podfile.lock`.
4. Go to terminal and run `pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not delete full Pod folder,I was facing this problem. In my Pod folder, there was no manifest.lock file so I just run these commands:

1. pod update

then

2. pod install

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32416553)